# How to execute java method in abstract class?

Tags: java, class, reference, this, ancestor

I have a method in abstract class that may be overriden in extended class or not. I'd like to call the original (not overriden) method. How to reference it? Example:

```
public abstract class A{

  protected MyResult my_method(){
    MyResult myResult;
    ...
    ... // Default implementation
    ...
    return myResult;
  }

 ...

 private void xy(){
   // I'd like to call my_method here
   if(!my_method().test()){
     // The function is not implemented well, I want ot use the original (abstract) method
     ...
     ... log a message for programmer
     ...
     this::A.my_method(); // I need something like this
   }
 }
}
```

I don't need any advice how to do it by different way. I only ask if there is a java syntax for referencing methods or properties in original class or in distant super-class.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to call the original (not overriden) method.

You can't do that from *outside* the subclass. From the subclass itself, you can call

```
super.my_method();
```

which will always call the superclass implementation, even if it's been overridden in this class. But to be able to do that outside the subclass would reduce encapsulation.

Comment: Your suggestion is usable in class B which extends A. I need to call it from a method written in A class.

Comment: @Hink: You can't do that. If you want to call code in class A from class A, put it in a final method to avoid the subclass being able to override it.

Comment: Ok, I belive You, I must reconcile with it.